# Number of positive divisors of $101^5$

Tags: number-theory

How do I figure out how many positive divisors there are when I have a number with an exponent?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html

Answer (score 1):

The number of positive divisors of any larger than $1$ integer $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ (where this is the unique prime factorization (see [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic))) is $(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)\cdots(\alpha_k+1)$.

So in this case, since $101$ is prime, the answer is $6$. In particular, all the positive divisors are simply $1,101, 101^2,\ldots, 101^5$.